# UIScrollVIew is not scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a UIScrollVIew. It contains a view with different controls. I added all of them to a view and then add the view to the UIScrollView. The scroll is not activated, and the content is not centered. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = texto.frame;
    frame.size.height = texto.contentSize.height;
    texto.frame = frame;

    [self configureView];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
     self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
     self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled= NO;
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;

}

-(void)configureView{

    self.texto.text = self.newsDetail.text;

    NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.newsDetail.image_large]];

    self.imagen.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    self.fecha.text = self.newsDetail.datePublish;

    self.titulo.text = self.newsDetail.title;


}
```

Header code:

```
@interface detailNewsController : UIViewController{

UIScrollView * __weak scrollView;
UIView       * __weak contentView;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) news *newsDetail;

@property ( weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView * contentView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imagen;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fecha;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titulo;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *texto;

-(void) configureView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you link your UIScrollView with a code variable. So check in interface builder if you enabled vertical scrolling (or horizontal one if you need it)

Comment: Hi gargo, in the interface builder I have this ContenView -> imagen, fecha, titulo, text. But ScrollView is not in the IB. Maybe this is the problem. thanks.

Comment: maybe by default it is not scrollable and you should set it by youself